# Is it possible to run a full monerod node on Android?

Tags: monerod, full-node, mobile, android-wallet

I have a spare Android smartphone and thought of running a full node on it, since its power consumption is very low and I wouldn't have to run my PC all day but still would have an up to date monerod in my home network. Thanks to a micro SD slot and Wifi, space and bandwidth is not an issue.

So is it possible to get monerod running on Android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are already people running [Monero full nodes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/53hug9/so_where_can_i_find_instruction_on_how_to_run_a/) with Android using GNURoot (which doesn't require a rooted phone, despite its name) as suggested by villabacho.

The proof of concept can be tested easily according to the steps listed by [binaryFate](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/53hug9/so_where_can_i_find_instruction_on_how_to_run_a/d7tiv1p/):

1. Install [GNUroot Debian](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gnuroot.debian)
2. Launch it, and type the following into the terminal:

> apt-get update && apt-get install wget bzip2
>
> wget -O monero.tar.bzip2 https://downloads.getmonero.org/arm
>
> bzip2 -d monero.tar.bzip2
>
> tar -xf monero.tar
>
> rm monero.tar
>
> monero/monero-wallet-cli (use --daemon-host  for a remote node)

If you have enough storage and want to have a better privacy, download and store the blockchain on a SD card. Otherwise it may be more feasible to use a remote node, which is faster and easier.

Comment: Thank you both for the advice! And you especially for the step by step tutorial, will try it shortly.

Comment: Here's what I did. On the remote computer:
`./monerod --rpc-bind-ip <external.ip.of.node> --restricted-rpc --confirm-external-bind`


On the phone:
`./monero-wallet-cli --wallet-file phone.bin --daemon-host <external.ip.of.node>`


Use Shift-Ctrl-v to paste in GNUroot. Also, it may be helpful to install [Hackers Keyboard] https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en so you can use the arrows, tab, and other keys.

Comment: c789 - are you running the node on the phone or the remote computer? The question was for running a node on the phone. Your commands make it look like your running the node on the remote computer. ..... ?

Comment: How do you get write permissions to your external sd card?

Answer (score 4):

You can also build monerod with the Android NDK and run it natively, instead of having to install GNURoot and running the Linux binaries.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/651un2/monero_v01031_cli_for_android_arm64/

Comment: This is great! Would you be willing to modify your answer to include the full instructions here instead of just the Reddit link to them?

Comment: Maybe after the PR gets merged would be better.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [GNURoot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=champion.gnuroot) to install and run Linux on your Android device, and then use the Linux version of monerod. This does not require rooting your device.

Comment: Except no phone have 80Gb of internal storage as writing to external sdcard is diabled after kitkat using this method.