# Generating a new wallet, locally, from your android wallet app

Tags: android-wallet

Has anyone tried implementing a wrapper between a wallet generator written in C/C++, like wallet2.cpp, using NDK (android native development kit) to communicate back to an android app?

Does anyone have a better idea to generate a new wallet from an android phone (locally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`monero-wallet-gui` can be seen as a "wrapper" for wallet2.cpp, and it can be built for android with NDK.

Alternatively, `monero-wallet-cli` can also be built with android NDK, but you would need a terminal emulator to run it (except if you use [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) ), so better to  just use the [provided arm binaries](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2706/110).

Finally, if it's only about generating keys, you can use a web page, like [moneromooo's wallet generator](https://github.com/moneromooo-monero/monero-wallet-generator) but stored locally.

**Edit**: i may have misread the question

Android java apps can use [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to have an instance of  [WalletManager](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/wallet/wallet2_api.h#L584) and call `WalletManager::createWallet`.

Comment: I liked the idea running a web page and do it through Android java interfacing to JavaScript. However, that may require to enable Javacript (if it's done through WebView) and that would make more vulnerable the app. 

I also though about generating the keys via a server (not very decentralize) and return the keys back to the user. But this will also create a layer of vulnerability that I dont like.

I'm still analyzing all the options I have for building a mobile wallet. What's Feasible and what's not.

Comment: You can access wallet c++ functions from java and vice versa with JNI. See [this from Qt android maintainer](https://www.qtdeveloperdays.com/sites/default/files/BogdanVatra_Extending_Qt_Android_Apps_with_JNI.pdf)